# how to submit html form with current hash location

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML form which i want to be able to submit with the current hash location

```
<form action="editcustomer.php?seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>#" method="post" name="form1">
```

Is this possible?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: The important question here, why do you need such a case? The parameters after hash cannot be sent to server side. If you tell the reason why you want to do this, we can help easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current hash value, you'll need something like this:

```
<form onSubmit="this.action='editcustomer.php'+location.hash" action="editcustomer.php" method="post" name="form">
```

off topic: It's common practice to do this, as it makes it possible to jump to the added anchor point, for example directly to the submitted form (#form-xy), thus enhancing user experience.

Comment: i don't know what the current hash location is, it will be different everytime

Comment: this adds another # location on the end of the url on form submit for some reason

Comment: hm, wait. the action should be without # in the form tag, right? it should work then...will fiddle...hm, jsfiddle is not that ok with forms...did it work? if you have the # in the initial html code, you'll need to strip it from location.hash, like location.hash.substr(1). ok?

Comment: yeah, my form looks exactly the same as your above code with an action of editcustomer.php

Comment: and your action still becomes editcustomer.php##the-current-hash - correct?

Comment: its showing editcustomer.php#currenthash#currenthash

Comment: due to events that may be firing two times, you could fix it in the on click handler, see updated answer.

Comment: You probably want to use the `onsubmit` attribute, not `onclick`.

Comment: probably, yes. was not sure if it's still possible to change the action at that point, but seems it is - good point.

Comment: May as well try. If you keep it as `onclick`, it'll add the hash every time that you click the form. That is, unless you expand the logic to check that it hasn't already been added.

Comment: jup. seems to work on submit. have nevertheless added a more failsafe solution that should work on click as well, specifying the action in a more absolute way.